# Json Object Ref in other json Object

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am developing an static website with angular, we've decided to put data in JSON files. But data is quite large and repetitive in nature.

So, I've decided to segregate data in multiple JSON files.

Like

foo.json

```
{ name: 'Avinash', Age: 88 }
```

Woo.json

```
{ City: 'Newyork', Street: 'Lincoln Park' }
```

Soo.Json

```
{City: 'Dubai', Street: "Marina"}
```

Loo.Json

```
 { Customer: 'foo.json', Address1: 'Woo.json', Address2: 'Soo.Json' }
```

It should compile all objects to gether on retrieval.

I've read json pointers concept [here](https://doc.4d.com/4Dv17/4D/17.2/JSON-Resolve-pointers.301-4387045.en.html), thought it might be useful. But I don't know how to do it in Typescript...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `json` files, create ts files and `export const` from there. Something like this:

foo.ts

```
export const foo = { name: 'Avinash', Age: 88 };
```

woo.ts

```
export const woo = { City: 'Newyork', Street: 'Lincoln Park' };
```

soo.ts

```
export const soo = {City: 'Dubai', Street: "Marina"};
```

loo.ts

```
import { foo } from './foo';
import { woo } from './woo';
import { soo } from './soo';

export const loo = { Customer: foo, Address1: woo, Address2: soo };
```

`loo` will contain an aggregated object that you can then import and use in the Component you want.

Something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { loo } from './data/loo';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(loo);
  }
}
```

Comment: With this approach wheneve I change data, I'd to rebuild and redeploy the side. I don't want that

Comment: you will have to retrieve this data from an API or something then. But it will essentially follow the same approach.

Comment: yeah, you are right there; but i"ll still want to explore a bit with json before giving up.

Comment: You can save JSON in file and access using service with get request. so that whenever you change data it will get it from files.